# Como incrementar o campo código do tipo varchar() automaticamente no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Eu preciso fazer um controle de estoque, onde o código dos produtos deve ser `varchar`, pois o código será formado pelo nome abreviado da categoria do produto seguido de um número sequencial, então não vou usar a coluna `product_ID` que é do tipo `int`, mas vou usar a `product_codev`, que é `varchar`, e preciso que ela seja auto incrementável. Como faço, tem como com `triggers`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deixe `product_ID` como `auto_increment` e faça uma trigger de `after insert`. Assim você pode montar o `product_codev` da forma que achar conveniente.

Agora se eu puder te dar uma sugestão, acho que este `product_codev` poderia ser montado na aplicação, já que aparentemente é algo para apresentar para o usuário e não para garantir a consistência dos dados.

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado pela resposta, acho que vou fazer o product_code na aplicação, o product_id já está funcionando mesmo! Não posso votar ainda na sua resposta porque sou usuário novo

Comment: Você pode aceitar como a resposta correta ;p